# Delete all files from Azure Storage subcontainer using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-storage

I have a container name A within which there is a sub container B.

I would like the PowerShell script to delete all blobs within B.

Comment: what do you mean by subcontainer? there is no such thing in Azure blob storage?

Comment: I have a script i worked up to download azure storage.. this might get you started: https://powershellposse.com/2017/09/03/azure-file-storage-download/

Answer (score 1):

For subcontainer, do you mean a virtual directory under a container. If so, You can try to run following script to delete the blobs in a virtual directory under a container. Change the container name, dirpath before you run the script.

For example, following script will delete all blobs in: testcontainer/dir1/dir2/, like testcontainer/dir1/dir2/blob1

```
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountname -StorageAccountKey $accountKey

$ContainerName = "testcontainer"
$dirpath = "dir1/dir2/"

$MaxReturn = 250
$Total = 0
$Token = $Null
do
{
    $Blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -prefix $dirpath -MaxCount $MaxReturn  -ContinuationToken $Token  -Context $ctx
    $Total += $Blobs.Count

    $Blobs | Remove-AzureStorageBlob

    if($Blobs.Length -le 0) { Break;}
    $Token = $Blobs[$Blobs.Count -1].ContinuationToken;
}
While ($Token -ne $Null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure doesn't provide the concept of hierarchical containers. There is actually only a single layer of containers.